# OpenCV's cv2.calibrateCamera produces inaccurate results with floating point image size

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to calibrate a camera using OpenCV's cv2.calibrateCamera() function to generate translation and rotation vectors, a camera matrix and distortion coefficients.

```
# list of normalized (0->1) 2D coordinate points generated by the front-end calibration process
calibration_pts = [[0.25,0.01], [0.25,0.99], [0.75, 0.01], [0.75, 0.99]]

# list of 3D coordinate points representing the real world dimensions of the court corresponding
# with the 2D points provided above.
tmp_src = [[-7620, 0, 0], [7620, 0, 0], [-1828.8, -8534.5, 0], [1828.8, -8534.4, 0]]

pts_dst = np.asarray(calibration_pts, dtype="float32")
pts_src = np.asarray(tmp_src, dtype="float32")

rms, c, d, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera([pts_src], [pts_dst], (1, 1), None, None)

projection_matrix = {
'rotation_vector': rvecs[0],
'translation_vector': tvecs[0],
'camera_matrix': c,
'distortion_coefficients': d,
}
```

I've noticed that when trying to project these points onto the 2D image plane, my Z axis is consistently wrong:
[Z-Axis Out of proportion with X and Y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgQuh.png)

This causes the image projection to be slightly wrong, indicating the point on which we're trying to focus is a bit higher than in reality.

I've played around with a variation of the above code that produces a more accurate projection matrix, using non-normalized values...

`calibration_pts = [[600,25], [600,995], [1500, 25], [1500, 995]]`

and in the cv2.calibrateCamera call, I specify the image size in non-normalized format..

`rms, c, d, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera([pts_src], [pts_dst], (7680, 4320), None, None)`

This produces much better results in terms of the image I'm able to produce to validate the accuracy of the projection matrix, but projectPoints calls using this projection matrix produce non-normalized 2D image coordinates and, ideally, I need it to produce normalized coordinates to be compatible with existing logic (the image size on which we're trying to project is often variable).

1. Is there some smarter way of providing the floating point coordinates to the calibrateCamera call so that the projection matrix it produces generates a more accurate Z-axis?
2. Is there some way of handling the resultant matrices produced by non-normalized data to cause it to produce normalized x,y values when I try to project points?